# How to align items according to screen size?

Tags: html, css

Hey am new to html and css. I have written a html but it display horizontally. I needed it to be vertically aligned. And when it is viewed in computer it should be divided into 4 parts and align vertically separately.

My HTML

```
  <div id="allPages">
    <div class="block">
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   <a href="">Happy</a>
   </div>
```

Example
In computer

[image: when it is viewed in computer]

In tabs and mobile

[image: When viewed in tabs and mobile]

Comment: try using either `grid` or `flexbox`: cfr. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ or https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Using [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grid templates in combination with media queries to change the layout according to the screen width as the example below:

```css
#allPages {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    #allPages {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    #allPages {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="allPages">
  <div class="block">
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
    <a href="">Happy</a>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <a href="">Sad</a>
    <a href="">Sad</a>
    <a href="">Sad</a>
    <a href="">Sad</a>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <a href="">Exited</a>
    <a href="">Exited</a>
    <a href="">Exited</a>
    <a href="">Exited</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many many ways. In the past we used floats.

Now, you have a choice of flex-box, columns, grid, and you can do each of them differently for different effect.

It also depends if you want to explicitly group them, or if you just want visual columns.

```
<section class='grouped-blocks'>
    <section class='block'>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
    </section>
    
    <section class='block'>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
    </section>
</section>
```

vs

```
<section class='column-blocks'>
    <!-- note / no parent blocks -->
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>

    <a href='#'>Link</a>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
</section>
```

and this may call for proper list markup depending on the meaning.

Here's an example of each. They all have pros and cons: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/JjRvPVM?editors=1100